# Appending parameter by default to every route by default

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my angular application, the route is defined below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':lang',
    children:
      [
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      ]
  },
]
```

Where the `:lang` is the language in which the application is displayed. The application URL is something like this `http://localhost:4300/en/dashboard`,

Now, to navigate from one route to another, each time the language needs to be prepended since it is the parent route. `<a routerLink="en/dashboard">Dashboard</a>`.

Is there any way to prepend the `:lang` to every route as the first parameter by default, so that the child components need not worry about appending the `en` before every url navigation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP interceptor.

I add a sample HTTP interceptor for your reference.

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const newReq = req.clone({
      params: req.params.append('defaultParam', 'value')
    });
    return next.handle(newReq);
  }
}
```

Then add the created **HTTP_INTERCEPTORS** providers in your app module class.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

// custom interceptor import here
// import { CustomInterceptor } from 'custom.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomInterceptor , multi: true }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```